# How to get strings and coordinates from the screenshot using python or monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python, ocr, monkeyrunner

Lets say i captured a screen shot using monkey runner. This screen shot contains some text ex: Contacts, Dialer et.c. I want to extract the strings and coordinates from the screenshot. So, in my monkey runner script, i can search for the string and get the coordinates. Using this coordinate i can use monkey runner to tap on the coordinate.
So, this will solve the purpose of searching a text in a screen and tapping on it.
Can somebody help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of OCR.

Try here:

https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/

It is probably easier to access the low level user interface elements than trying to figure out what reads on the screenshot. However, the question lacks related information about used software, operating system, etc.

Comment: Doesn't monkey runner provider its own APIs for accessing the widgets without need to scape the screen?

Comment: How to access low level user interface elements?